Dry validation. How to send param in to macros
json (simple example):
{
  "person": {
    "birthday": "1990-10-10"
  },
  "achievement": {
    "date_appr_r": "2022-05-21"
  }
}

My contract:
class CreateContract < BaseContract
  json do
    required(:person).hash do
      required(:birthday).value(:date)
    end
    required(:achievement).hash do
      required(:date_appr_r).value(:date)
    end
  end

  rule(person: :birthday).validate(:person_birthday)
  rule(achievement: :date_appr_r).validate(:achievement_date_appr_r)
end

I need a check that date_appr_r cannot be earlier than the date of birth.
Question: How can I pass the birthday to the achievement_date_appr_r macro?
I've read all the documentation and hope I'm missing something

class CreateContract < BaseContract
  params do
    required(:person).hash do
      required(:birthday).value(:date)
    end
    required(:achievement).hash do
      required(:date_appr_r).value(:date)
    end
  end

  rule(:person, :achievement) do
    key(:dates).failure(:invalid) if values[:person][:birthday] >= values[:achievement][:date_appr_r]
  end
end

and calling contract
params = { person: { birthday: DateTime.new(2024, 1, 1) }, achievement: { date_appr_r: DateTime.new(2024, 1, 2) } }
validation = CreateContract.new.call(params)


I want to use this rule in other contracts, so I put it in macros.

rule(:person, :achievement).validate(:achievement_date_appr_r) ?
